# What exactly can be placed in an answer

Tags: discussion

There seems to be a lot of confusion over this [cw post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90599/46918). My intention with posting it as an answer was to allow easier edit access to the scoreboard for competitors to place their scores onto a leaderboard. This makes it easier than having to manually maintain a leaderboard. Also having the leaderboard as an answer allows the main post (which is already lengthy) to be cleaner and more readable. 


I have seen this system used already [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25375/46918) where an answer to a question is used as a spot to explain the specifications for a submission wrapper of non-java code. I feel like this does not conflict with our help center's guidelines on answers, but I would like to see community consensus here, and If there as a consensus to have me move the scoreboard, I will.

Comment: I think the real problem is that typical cops and robbers challenges have two separate threads, which mostly eliminates the need for a scoreboard. Probably the best solution would be an automated JS scoreboard, if you feel up to writing it.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I don't know javascript, (I should really learn it) do you think you would be willing to help me out with a scoreboard. It should be  a fairly simple modification of most code golf scoreboarrds suprisingly.

Comment: Specifically, item 5. *Answers that aren't actually answers. This includes anything but code that is intended to solve the challenge.*

Comment: @Dennis so could you help clarify how the wrapper class is considered a valid answer (so I can better understnad the rule)

Comment: That's not an *answer* and shouldn't have been posted as such.

Comment: @Dennis ok, thanks for clarifying